# Find the sum of the diverge series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

When talking about the famous sum 1+2+3+..., we can define the zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}$ for $Re(s)>1$. Then by doing analytic continuation, we can find the result is $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$.

So how about this sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^n$.

For example, I can define a function like this: $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-sn}$, and do the analytic continuation, and get the result for $f(-1)$. Is this possible? And if the result is not a closed form solution, how to get its numeric value?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^n$ is divergent !

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403347/value-of-divergent-sum-sum-n-0-infty-1n-nn)

Comment: @Fred Obviously, and the asker stated that in his question. He is asking about analytic continuation.

Comment: Analytic continuation is hardly a reliable method.

Answer (score -1):

Underwood gave  in [$1946$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261), for $p> 2$,the bounds
$$p^p\left(1+\frac{1}{4 (p-1)}\right)<\sum_{n=1}^{p}n^n<p^p\left(1+\frac{2}{e (p-1)}\right) $$

Comment: Not what he asked for.

Answer (score -2):

Try this method ([Infinite series as integral representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572175/infinite-series-as-integral-representation)). I don't think we have such advanced tools  in math to get closed form but it should work as numerical method

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f (k)=-2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {F(x-\frac {1}{2}+it)}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt $