# Infinite series as integral representation

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, transformation, divergent-series, analytic-continuation

Greetings infinity series enjoyers. Not so long ago, I hypothesised existing of some equation connected with infinity summation, but could't prove it. The equation looks like $\sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f(k)=-2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {F (x-1/2+it)}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt$ and primarly I was asking, if thats correct.  Now a days I found a simple proof which is down below but when I know it's true, I have diferent questions. Does it has any value for mathematic? I mean equation is very general and works for divergent series too. Maybe it will find some use in mathematics. It is very similar to Abel-plana formula but that equationis look nicer for me and work for divergent series.

Proof

Let's firstly use Euler-Maclouren summation with some variation.

$\displaystyle  \sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f (k)=- \left [ \frac {F (x)B_0}{0!}-\frac {f (x)B_1}{1!}+ \frac {f^{'}(x)B_2}{2!}- \frac {f^{''}(x)B_3}{3!}+ \frac {f^{'''}(x)B_4}{4!}  ...\right]$

Now write Bernouli numbers in integral form in such way, that they will create Taylor series.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f (k)=-2 \pi \left [ \frac{F (x)}{0!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {(-\frac {1}{2}+it)  ^0}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt +\frac {f (x)}{1!}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {(-\frac {1}{2}+it)^1}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt  + \frac {f^{'}(x)}{2!}   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {(-\frac {1}{2}+it)^2}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt...\right]$

And just write Taylor series in form of function.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f (k)=-2 \pi  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac { F (x)  \frac{\left(-\frac {1}{2}+it\right)^0 }{0! }+  f (x) \frac {\left(-\frac {1}{2}+it\right)}{1!}+ f^{'}(x)  \frac {\left(-\frac {1}{2}+it\right)^2}{2!}...}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt =-2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {F(x-\frac {1}{2}+it)}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt $

Comment: What is the relationship between $f$ and $F$? Is $F$ some kind of transform of $f$ (e.g. Fourier, Laplace, or Mellin)? Or was $F$ a typo that should have been $f$?

Comment: F it's just antideritative of f. But without +C term

Comment: Without the assumption $x \in \mathbb Z$, which is not important, your formula becomes
$$\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{-1/2 - i \infty}^{-1/2 + i \infty}
 \pi^2 \csc^2( \pi s) \, F(s + x) \, ds =
-\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \operatorname* {Res}_{s = k} \,
  \pi^2 \csc^2( \pi s) \, F(s + x).$$
This is false for $F(s) = 1$ (we cannot close the contour in such a way that the integral over the remainder of the contour is negligible; the sequence of integrals over $|s + 1/2| = n \land -\pi/2 < \arg(s + 1/2) < \pi/2$ tends to a finite non-zero limit).

Comment: Is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5Be%5E%28-n%5E2%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2Cintegral%5B2pi+1%2F2+sqrt%28π%29+erf%281-1%2F2%2Bi+t%29%2F%28e%5E%28pi+t%29%2Be%5E%28-+pi+t%29%29%5E2%2C%7Bt%2C-50%2C50%7D%5D) a counterexample with $f(k)=e^{-k^2},x=1$?

Answer (score 2):

Example ...
Take $f(u) = 1/u^2; x=1$.  Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} .
\tag1$$
This conjecture tells us that
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt}{(\frac12+it)\cosh^2(\pi t)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} .
\tag2$$
Numerically, it works.  Can we evaluate $(2)$?  The imaginary part vanishes since it is odd, so $(2)$ reduces to
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt}{(\frac14+t^2)\cosh^2(\pi t)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} .
\tag3$$

---

Similarly
$$
\pi\,\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac {1-4\,{t}^{2}}{ \left(1+ 4\,{t}^
{2} \right) ^{2}  \cosh^2 \left( \pi\,t \right) }}
\,{\rm d}t = \zeta(3) .
$$