# Integral representation for series of any order

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, transformation, divergent-series, analytic-continuation

Hello infinity series enjoyers. If my calulations are correct, I think I made some integral representation of any divergent and convergent seris of any order s. All calulations and the question are down below.

$\displaystyle   \sum\limits^s_{k=x}     \;\!\!\;\!  \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \lower -0.2pt {\infty}  \quad \!\!\!  f (k)  =\overbrace {
\sum_{k_{s-1}=x} ^{\infty} ... \sum_{k_1=k_2}^{\infty} \sum_{k_0=k_1}^{\infty}}^{s}f (k_0)
=\sum_{k=x}^{\infty}f (k)\frac {( k-x+s-1)!}{\Gamma (s)(k-x)!}$

We can prove that ([Infinite series as integral representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572175/infinite-series-as-integral-representation;))

$\displaystyle   \sum\limits^1_{k=x}     \;\!\!\;\!  \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \lower -0.2pt {\infty}  \quad \!\!\!    f (k) = 
\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {\frac{d^{n}}{dx^n}F^s (x) \frac{d^{n}}{dh^n}  \left( \frac{-h}{e^h-1}   \right)    }{n!}   =-\frac {i \pi}{2}\int_{-\frac {1}{2}-i\infty}^{-\frac {1}{2}+i\infty}  \csc^2 (\pi t) \int f(x+t)dt dt $

Now we have to just substitute first equation to secound

$\displaystyle   \sum\limits^s_{k=x}     \;\!\!\;\!  \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \lower -0.2pt {\infty}  \quad \!\!\!    f (k) =-\frac {i \pi  }{2}\int_{-\frac {1}{2}-i\infty}^{-\frac {1}{2}+i\infty}  csc^2 (\pi t) \int
  f (t+x)\frac {( t+s-1)!}{\Gamma (s)(t)!}   dt dt
=\frac {i \pi (-1)^{s}}{2\Gamma (s)}\int_{-\frac {1}{2}-i\infty}^{-\frac {1}{2}+i\infty}  F^{s}(x+t)\Psi_s (t)dt$

Where $F^s$ is s ordered antideritative of f and $\Psi_s(t)$ is defined down below.

$\displaystyle \Psi_s(t)= \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \left [ \frac {d^{n}}{dt^{n}}csc^2 (\pi t) \right] \left [   \frac {d^{s-1-n}}{dt^{s-1-n}} \frac {(t+s-1)!}{ t!}   {s\choose n+1}  \right]$

But we can write $F^{s}(x+t)$ as Taylor series and compere it to generalised Euler-Maclouren Summation to determinate  $(-1)^{s}$ for non itintegers

$\displaystyle   \sum\limits^s_{k=x}     \;\!\!\;\!  \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \lower -0.2pt {\infty}  \quad \!\!\!  f (k)  =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {   F^{s-n}(x)}{n!}  (-1)^s\int_{-\frac {1}{2}-i\infty}^{-\frac {1}{2}+i\infty}(-t)^n   \frac {i \pi }{2\Gamma (s)}\Psi_s (t)dt = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}      \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {F^{s-n} (x) \frac{d^{n}}{dh^n}  \left(   \frac{-h}{e^h-1}   \right)^s    }{n!}   $

And that imply

$\displaystyle   \sum\limits^s_{k=x}     \;\!\!\;\!  \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \lower -0.2pt {\infty}  \quad \!\!\!  f (k) =\frac {i \pi e^{i \pi s}}{2\Gamma (s)}\int_{-\frac {1}{2}-i\infty}^{-\frac {1}{2}+i\infty}  F^{s}(x+t)\Psi_s (t)dt $

Is there any simple equation for $\Psi_s (t) $? Maybe I overcomplicated some transformations.

Comment: "infinity series enjoyers" nice !

Comment: If you do use Wolfram Alpha, use the [Sum](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html),[NIntegrate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html),  and [D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) commands. Unfortunately Wolfram Alpha [fails on complex bound integrals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Nintegrate%5Bgamma%28s%29%28-%28-1%29%29%5E-s%2C%7Bs%2C-1%2F2-sqrt%28-1%29+infty%2C-1%2F2%2Bsqrt%28-1%29+infty%7D%5D) sometimes

Comment: What exactly does $\sum\limits ^{s} _{k=x} f(k)$ stand for? What does “symbol of infinity analytic series of function $f (k)$, from $k=x$ with $s$ order” mean?

Comment: You have definition on the first equation. By saying 'infinity analytic series' I mean it gives values to divergent series. And for s order I mean that summation operator is composed s times. I wonna write first symbol with infinity in the middle of sigma but I don't have such LaTex skills

Comment: I think you could replace $e^{i\pi}$ with $-1$. I'm not experienced in complex numbers so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I just did opisite you write. I replaced -1 to $e^{i\pi} $

Comment: @Wreior `\sum\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\infty` gives $\sum\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\infty$ or you can say $f^s(x)=\underbrace{f(f(\dots f(x)))}_{s \text{ number of } f\text{‘s}}$

Comment: Thank you. The only one thing bigger than this infinity symbol in the middle of summation is your good hearth

Comment: It would help convince me of your intentions if you worked out the example of $s=2$.  The significance of overlaying the infinity symbol on the middle of a summation sign escapes me.  Perhaps a link to where others have used that notation would help me.

Comment: [$f(n)=n^{-2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=sum%5B1%2Fn%5E2%2C%7Bn%2C2%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2C+-+pi+NIntegrate%5B-1%2F%282%2Bi+t-1%2F2%29+csc%28pi%28i+t-1%2F2%29%29%5E2%2F2%2C%7Bt%2C+-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D) and [$f(n)=-n^{-n}(\ln(n)+1)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=sum%5B-x%5E%28-x%29+%281+%2B+log%28x%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C2%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2C+-+pi+NIntegrate%5B%282%2Bi+t-1%2F2%29%5E%28-+%282%2Bi+t-1%2F2%29%29+csc%28pi%28i+t-1%2F2%29%29%5E2%2F2%2C%7Bt%2C+-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D) work for $s=1$ even though the cases converge . Is $\sum_{m=a}^\infty\sum_{n=m}^\infty f(n)$ used often?

Comment: Don't know and don't care. It's not about the use. It's about pure beautyfulness. But thank for checking some cases

Comment: Very based calculation